# Using variable name as array index

Tags: java, arrays, variables

I have few files which I put in array. 
I shuffle the files so that it can be displayed in random order. 
How to know that array index 0 is actually image1.txt or image2.txt or image3.txt?
Thanks in advance.

```
String[] a = {"image1.txt","image2.txt","image3.txt"};
List<String> files = Arrays.asList(a);
Collections.shuffle(files);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### INCORRECT - see explanation

Note: Arrays.asList() will create a NEW list with the contents of the passed array. The original array will not be modified at all when you use Collections.shuffle().

### Explanation

Peter has correctly pointed our that Arrays.asList() does NOT make a copy. The returned list is "write-through" back to the original array. Shuffling the list will shuffle the contents of the original array. Also worth noting that the list is immutable (new elements cannot be added) but typically I find that the use of Arrays.asList() involves immutable lists anyway.

```
files.get(0); // get the first elements in shuffled list, random

// as greg said
int index = files.indexOf(a[0]); // find out where "image1.txt" is in the list
files.get(index); // get "image1.txt" back from the list
```

Comment: Actually Arrays.asList() is just a wrapper for the original array, it doesn't take a copy so changes to one change both.

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked that! Thanks Peter! Not sure how useful my answer is now ...

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do.

To access the first element of the shuffled list, use `files.get(0)`.

If you want to know where each element is gone, I suggest you take another approach to it. Create a list of integers from `0` to `a.length() - 1`, inclusive and shuffle that list. Then manually permute the array `a` to a new collection.

Comment: Yeah it's java.  The Collections.shuffle gives it away.

Comment: @JaredPar: camelCasing is also a huge hint.

Comment: @Mehrdad, I usually see Camel casing as a typo :)

Comment: @JaredPar: Lol! It was the same for me until a couple days ago I had to work on umbarco CMS's source which is full of camelCasing :)